# Who modify the type of $$ in a yacc grammar

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I want to change the define $$ as a struct in the following grammar i have declared yylval as str, but i have errors when compile the .c file with gcc

```
gcc *.c -ly 
tp.l: In function ‘yylex’:
tp.l:12: error: request for member ‘sum’ in something not a structure or union
y.tab.c:1035: error: conflicting types for ‘yylval’
tp.y:11: note: previous declaration of ‘yylval’ was here
```

the yacc file:

```
 %{
        #include <ctype.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        typedef struct {
            int val;
            int cpt;
        } str;

        str yylval;

%}
        %start  start 
        %token  number

%%
    start : number'+'number'\n'
    ;

%%

int main(void)
{
        yyparse();
        return 0;
}
```

the lex file :

```
%option noyywrap

%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    #include"y.tab.h"
%}

%%
[0-9]+  {
            yylval = atoi(yytext); 
            return number;
        }

"+"     return '+';
\n      return '\n';
" " ;

%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define your own `yylval`. The generated code already defines this. Use the `%union` directive to define the type indirectly. If that is not suitable, then what you can do is redefine the macro `YYSTYPE` which expands to arbitrary type specifiers. For instance:

```
struct my_semantic_attributes {
  int foo;
  /* ... */
};

#define YYSTYPE struct my_semantic_attributes
```

Comment: is yylval = atoi(yytext); fine our yylval.val = atoi(yytext);

Comment: I believe `yylval = atoi(yytext);` is possible, if you `#define YYSTYPE int` (which is rather limiting).

Comment: What if i'm using #define YYSTYPE str.

Comment: In that case, `yylval` is of type `str`, and so of course `yylval.val = `.

Comment: tp.l: In function ‘yylex’:
tp.l:12: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: If you use `%union` to define the type, then yacc will put a declaration of it in `y.tab.h`, as well as an `extern YYSTYPE yylval;` declaration. If you use `#define YYSTYPE`, you have to provide these declarations yourself (like in your own header which is included by the parser and lexer).